# nested Ajax response data acess not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am beginner at javascript , I am trying to calculate distance between two postcodes.

I am using a REST api with ajax get method to get latitude and longitude of a post code then send another ajax call to a servlet which returns the distance in json format.

Now I am having a hard time accessing the returned json string. When i check what's inside the `data` variable i only find the json elements returned on the first call. But when I check on my browser i find both of the ajax called successfully returned and i can see the json string of second ajax which returned the distance in browser console.

nested ajax returns following

```
{"distance":"0.005011484329483577"} (found it from browser inspect element console)
```

I need to be able to store the value of distance into a variable.I tried using data.distance. but it returns undefined.

maybe scope problem?

please help

```
    /* 
     * Nurul Alam
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#PostCodeLookUp').submit(function(){
            var p = document.getElementById("postCode").value;
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'+p,
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                //data:$('#updateUserName').serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                        var lat = data.result.latitude;
                        var lng = data.result.longitude;
                        //send the data in a ajax call to a servlet which process the data and returns the distance
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'postCodeConverterServlet',
                            type:'POST',
                            dataType:'xml',
                            data:$.param({lat: lat, lng:lng}),
                            success:function(){
                              alert(data.distance);  
                            } 
                        });                                        
                        //
                        //$('#displayName').html(d);
                        //$('#displayName').slideDown(500);
                    }else{                    
                       $('#displayName').html("Problem");                    
                    } 
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do note that this is `javascript` *not* `java`, important distinction if you go googling for stuff  and what not  ;)

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MatthewCliatt The OP included much of what you are asking for here and certainly more than enough to plainly see the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the success function of your second ajax call, you are accessing the return from the first *again* by using `data`. Change your second ajax success function to the below giving it its own parameter name for its own response, then use that. You can give the argument a more meaningful name if you'd like but this would work:

```
success:function(nestedData){
    alert(nestedData.distance);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much man... :D u saved me... Its solved...
Stackoverflow rules...
The issue was regarding scope and nestedData.distance did the trick.